# Targeting iPhones independently from Android devices with CSS media queries

Tags: android, iphone, html, css, html-email

Is there any way to target iPhones independently from Android devices and vice-versa with CSS media inquiries. This is for an HTML e-mail.

We've tried multiple methods, but they all seem to overlap.

We want to limit table sizes in devices with a max-device-width of 480, but only for Android based devices.

Below is what I've tried most recently. The iPhone (testing in Litmus) ignores the second media query and keeps the width at 300px.

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
      table[class="table"], td[class="cell"] {

width: 300px;

}
}


/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
    @media
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
      table[class="table"], td[class="cell"] {

width: 100%;

}
}
```

Comment: I thought most email clients stripped out style tags?  Is that not true on iOS and Android Mail Apps?  If so that is cool.

Comment: Do you have any solution finally? I am facing the same situation too.

Answer (score 2):

try -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio and min-device-pixel-ratio

```
 /* iPhone 4 ----------- */
    @media
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
```

see http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: That works well for targeting the iPhone, but the issue I'm having is then being able to target Android devices separately so I can change the width based on the device. I can't seem to isolate one from another.

Comment: What would you do to target iPhone 2-3s together with 4? they have a pixel ratio of 1, right?